# .replace() not replacing items

Tags: pandas

I have a df like so:

```
ID     LC
1      Corn  
2      Forest/Shrubland/Deciduous Forest/Evergreen Forest/Mixed Forest
3      Blank_/Peas
```

and I am trying to replace some of the `LC` items.

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

replace = {'Blank_/Peas': 'Other Crops', 'Forest/Shrubland/Deciduous Forest/Evergreen Forest/Mixed Forest': 'Forest/Shrub'}
df['LC'].replace(replace, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

but this returns:

```
    ID     LC
    1      Corn  
    2      Forest/Shrubland/Deciduous Forest/Evergreen Forest/Mixed Forest
    3      Other Crops
```

I am not sure why some items are replaced and others are not.

This also does not work:

```
df['LC'].replace(replace, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Why do you have regex set to true?

Comment: because it also didn't work without it

Comment: I think you have the keys/values conflated in your `replace` dictionary

Comment: I could not reproduce the error but if you have exact matches then I would just do `df['LC'].map(replace)`

Comment: I see how it appears that way, but `df.LC.unique()` returns :  `u'Forest/Shrubland/Deciduous Forest/Evergreen Forest/Mixed Forest'` for the one that doesn't replace

Comment: @TedPetrou that does the trick.  I have never had a problem replacing with `inplace=True` before, but that was the problem.  Very odd.

Comment: I don't have a problem with `inplace=True` with your original code. You will also have to append `.fillna(df['LC'])` with my code above to get it to work but `replace` should work. I would make sure you have upgraded to 0.19.2

Comment: I did, `df['LC'] = df['LC'].replace(replace)`